# Interrupt ID to name mapping

Tags: linux, interrupt, interrupt-handling, android-hardware

I am running some benchmarks on a Linux system, and recording the interrupt arrival by noting the ID of the interrupt's. I would like to map the interrupt ID to its name.

For example, interrupt no. 7 corresponds to pagefault exception.

cat /proc/interrupt is not helping.
In this file, some interrupts are noted by their ID (ex : 0 for timer interrupt), and some interrupts are noted by a crytic MACRO (ex : PMI for performance monitoring interrupts)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are talking about an intel setups.

Try the OSDEV website for questions about interrupts.   In particular: http://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Vector_Table

Note that the CPU traps and interrupt vectors can overlap, and that interrupt numbers can be reprogrammed by the operating system.

See [How to get the interrupt vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379668/how-to-get-the-interrupt-vector)